# Swagger UI example response for Dictionary return type

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have a C# ASP.NET API with an endpoint that returns a `Dictionary<int,string>` (applies to all Dictionary returns).

When viewing the API documentation in Swagger UI, the response example is displayed as `{}`.

[image: Response example in Swagger UI]

I have tried using the following attributes on my controller method:

```cs
[SwaggerResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(List<Door>))]  [ProducesResponseType(typeof(List<Door>), 200)]
[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Country>))]
```

Controller Method

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves a Dictionary of key-value pairs of Property ids and Property descriptions
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x">Test.</param>
    /// <param name="y">Example.</param>
    /// <returns>Dictionary of PropertyId, Property Description pairs</returns>
    /// <remarks>Excludes Properties that the user is restricted from</remarks>
    [Route("Test/{x}/{y}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public Dictionary<int, string> Test(bool x, bool y)
    {
        return propertiesService.GetPropertyList(x, y);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to fetch the result? Do you see why it is not possible to provide any schema to it?

Comment: What version of ASP.NET are you using? And What library are you using for swagger? Can you please provide a [mre]?

Comment: It wont be feasible to change the return type (provide a schema). Net Framework 4.7.2, 
Swashbuckle

Comment: What version of Swashbuckle?

Comment: Swashbuckle 5.6

Comment: Can you please post a [mre] somewhere like github?